# Makefile works on OS X but not on Ubuntu

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu

I was wondering if StackOverflow could help me out today! So I am currently finishing up a project in C for one of my CS courses at Uni and I am running into a funny problem. When I use the commands 'make' and 'make test' on my OSX environment it runs just fine, but when I test it on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine, it gives me these errors:

make: prim:Command not found

makefile:32: recipe for target 'test failed.

make: ***[test] Error 127

Here is my makefile code below, any help is appreciated.

```
OBJS = main.o scanner.o AM.o binheap.o CDLL.o node.o prim.o vertex.o
OPTS = -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c99

main : $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OPTS) $(OBJS) -o prim -lm

main.o : main.c scanner.h AM.h binheap.h CDLL.h node.h prim.h vertex.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c main.c

scanner.o : scanner.c scanner.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c scanner.c

node.o : node.c node.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c node.c

AM.o : AM.c AM.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c AM.c

prim.o : prim.c prim.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c prim.c

binheap.o : binheap.c binheap.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c binheap.c
CDLL.o : CDLL.c CDLL.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c CDLL.c

vertex.o : vertex.c vertex.h
    gcc $(OPTS) -c vertex.c

test: prim
     @echo ###############################
     @echo TESTING GRAPH1.TXT
     @echo prim graph1.txt
     @echo ###############################
     prim graph1.txt
     @echo ###############################
     @echo TESTING GRAPH2.TXT
     @echo prim graph2.txt
     @echo ###############################
     prim graph2.txt
     @echo ###############################

clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS) main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change this:

```
main : $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OPTS) $(OBJS) -o prim -lm
```

to:

```
prim : $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OPTS) $(OBJS) -o prim -lm
```

Also, unless `prim` is somehow on the path, your shell won't find it.  It's probably better to write test rule as:

```
test: prim
     @echo ###############################
     @echo TESTING GRAPH1.TXT
     @echo prim graph1.txt
     @echo ###############################
     ./prim graph1.txt
     @echo ###############################
     @echo TESTING GRAPH2.TXT
     @echo prim graph2.txt
     @echo ###############################
     ./prim graph2.txt
     @echo ###############################
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you EDIT: Well it fixed my errors but now it will just print out    prim graph1.txt but then never print out the actual output?

Comment: Does `prim` generate output?  My guess is that it's not. :-)

Comment: It does on mac, I believe it because I am not initializing all my variables to NULL to begin with and Linux doesn't like that

Answer (score 2):

```
make: prim:Command not found
```

That error message tells you what's wrong. `prim` can't be found in `PATH` on Ubuntu. Assuming `prim` is the program you just built in the local directory, you should be running `./prim` in your Makefile.